# Google Spreadsheet onEdit event is undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I try to reproduce simple `onEdit()` example for Google Spreadsheets from that video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L1_nIhiVc5M&list=PLJnkyVAO-LM6VAUetaNIvwADp0XF-LlrE&index=85

I have a spreadsheet and script bound to it. I granted access to spreadsheet to the script.
The script has the following code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log("something was edited " + e.old_value);
}
```

When I edit something in spreadsheet function executes but `e` is undefined. This is how result of execution looks in stackdriver:

stackdriver_screenshot:
[image: stackdriver_screenshot]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Typo. There is no property ``old_value`` in  event `e`.See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation or see your video again.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*The event object parameter you are trying to access is `e.oldValue`, not `e.old_value`.*

#### More Information:

According to the documentation for Event Objects:

> **oldValue**: Cell value prior to the edit, if any. Only available if the edited range is a single cell. Will be undefined if the cell had no previous content.

So in this case you can rectify this with a simple code change:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log("something was edited " + e.oldValue);
}
```

#### References:

- [Event Objects | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Google Sheets Events - `onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)